# Accessing google spreadsheet api to fetch data with filter

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

I am trying to fetch data with specific name from a google spreadsheet using java. I am able to fetch complete data from a column using google api. I specify range as "sheet1!B:B" for example. However, I am not understanding

1. How to fetch data from multiple columns. How should I pass the range?
2. How do I specify the data filter for columns.

Any guidance would be really appreciated. I am unable to find it in github or googlespreadsheet api docs. Please help me out

Currently I have code to fetch all values from googlespread sheet using below code

```
String spreadsheetId="spreadseet id";

String range="Sheet!A2:zz";

Sheets service = new Sheets.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();

Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.Get request=service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId, range);

ValueRange response = request.execute();
```

Comment: Are the columns you want to fetch continuous or discontinuous? Can you please share the request code you already have?

Comment: I am using this GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values/{range} and parsing Range as <Sheetname>!A:zz to fetch complete data. I am trying out api in google apis get values api page. If i need single column I specify my range as <Sheetname>!A:A. It fetches the data but i need more capabilities

Comment: Please update your question with your code :)

Answer (score 2):

Let's take the official example provided by google [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit#gid=0):

[image]

> 1. How to fetch data from multiple columns. How should I pass the range?

This is the range:

```
String range = "Class Data!A2:F";
```

Which means fetch all the data from the cell `A2` to the column `F` of the sheet with the name `Class Data`.

> 2. How do I specify the data filter for columns.

Once you have all the data you can filter it in a normal for-loop. For example if we want only the column 1 and 2:

```
List<List<Object>> values = request.execute().getValues();
System.out.println("Name, Gender");
for (List row : values) {
    System.out.println(row.get(0)+", "+row.get(1));
}
```

The output will be:

```
Name, Gender
Alexandra, Female
Andrew, Male
Anna, Female
```

More info on the [official Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java).

Comment: This works for me. However, passing he query would have been a reliable solution for any other features in googlespreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [RestedBox](https://www.restedbox.com/) to access your Google Sheets and local spreadsheet data through an API, including querying. I've been using it for some POC's instead of a database.